# Excel - formula not auto-refreshing after undo/redo

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Example: I have a formula in column C that is a function of values in columns A and B.  When I change a value in A or B and press enter, the value in C auto-updates.  However, when I Ctrl-Z, the value in Column C does not automatically revert back to the original value before my change. In the past, I have used undo/redo as a quick check on how my changes affect the formula, but that no longer seems to work.  Any ideas?

My workbook calculation is set to 'Automatic'. I have Excel 2016.

Comment: What is the function you are using?  I cannot replicate this.

Comment: Simple division: = (B1/A1) - 1

Comment: @JES which function(s) are A1 & B1 using?  What happens if you use `=A1` and `=B1` is separate cells?

Comment: @ashleedawg user entered values. Referring to them in separate cells didn't do anything.

Comment: @JES - alright, what if you use, in C1 `=A1` or `=B1`?  Does the same thing happen?

Comment: @JES Also, in the status bar (bottom left of Excel window) does it say anything besides "Ready"?

Comment: @ashleedawg C1 = A1 same problem. Status is 'Ready'

Comment: @JES - and when it's calculating, it calculates correctly?  Strange.  There has to be something else affecting it. can you give an example of the value in A1?

Comment: @JES - Try this: save, close Excel, reboot the computer, create a new Workbook, and try a similar calculation.  That *must* work - so after that try the non-working workbook, if it's still not working, copy & paste *values* and *formulas* to the working workbook, and see what happens.

Comment: @ashleedawg your suggestion worked.  This has been an issue for over a week, and I could have sworn I've saved, closed, and rebooted before, but apparently not.  I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: Weird stuff can happen sometimes, a strange set of circumstances that don't seem to have a pattern.  I've spent more time than that on some seemingly-simple issues.  (Javascript drives me batty for that: JES - *"why can't it just *say* missing semicolon at the end of that line!"*) ...anyhow all good, it's not a waste of time (especially if I now write it as an answer and you accept it ;) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's such a seemingly-simply problem, this will help find the issue:

1. save workbook
2. close Excel
3. reboot the computer
4. create a new workbook
5. try a similar calculation

That must work - so after that try the non-working workbook, if that one's  *still* not working, copy & paste values and formulas to the "working workbook".  The problem should now be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug (as far as I can tell) in Excel. I'm using Microsoft 365 and this happens there as well.

You can easily replicate this bug by doing the following:

- Create a new blank sheet
- Type X in A1 and =A1 in B1. B1 will now also contain "X"
- Type Y in A1. B1 will now also contain "Y"
- Press Ctrl+Z. A1 will now contain "X" while B1 will still contain "Y".

Somehow it seems that Ctrl+Z doesn't trigger the calculation event.

EDIT: Aaaand now it suddenly works again. This is weird. Seems completely arbitrary whether it works or not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).